# Git Bash Terminal closing automatically after installing?

Tags: github, git-bash

Git bash is closing automatically in a fraction of second after installation how to fix this?

Comment: After _installation_? Why would the bash window even be open during installation? How would you run it before it had bee installed?

Answer (score 0):

check whether you've installed git properly, open your command prompt or git bash then type

```
    git --version

    C:\Users\07>git --version
    git version 2.16.1.windows.1
```

if you're able to get git version something like this then git is installed in your system. If you're getting any errors or not able to open the command prompt or git bash just check whether you've added git path to your system if not add path and check it once again. Refer [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) for the installation process and check with the release notes as well.

Comment: Hei!! Meghna thanks for your comment. The problem has been solved. Initially, I have installed git in C:/ drive now I tried in D:/ cool its working.